# Function composition, tell me if it's right please

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

I have to do the function composition $f \circ f$

$$f(x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if} \;x=1\\ 
x-1 \quad \text{if}\; x>1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$f(f(x))=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if}\; x=1\\ 
x-2 \quad\text{if}\; x>1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Is it right?

Comment: Can you clarify your notation further? What is $f$ in your piecewise definition? What about $i$?

Comment: Looking at x = 1 it certainly doesn't look right... when x = 1 f(x) = 2 so f(f(x)) = f(2) = 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.

When $x=1$, $f(x)=f(1)=2$ so at this $x$, $$f(f(x))=f(f(1))=f(2)=2-1=1$$ instead of $2$.

When $x>1$, $f(x)=x-1$ so at such $x$, $$f(f(x))=f(x-1)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if} \;x-1=1\implies x=2\\ 
x-1-1 \quad \text{if}\; x-1>1 \implies x>2\\ 
\end{array}
\right.$$ Hence, $$f(f(x))=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1 \quad\text{if} \;x=1\\
2\quad\text{if}\; x=2\\ 
x-2 \quad  \text{if}\; x>2\\ 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Answer (score 3):

$f(f(x))$ is 
$$f(f(x))=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if} \;f(x)=1\\ 
f(x)-1 \quad \text{if}\; f(x)>1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
but $f(x)=1 \iff x=2$, and $f(x)>1 \iff (x>2 \text{ or } x=1)$. Therefore,
$$f(f(x))=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if} \;x=2\\ 
f(x)-1 \quad \text{if}\; x>2 \text{ or } x=1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2 \quad\text{if} \;x=2\\ 
x-2 \quad \text{if}\; x>2\\  
1 \quad \text{if}\; x=1\\ 
\end{array}
\right.
$$